# Can anyone give me some clarity on Q2 where PLSR is concerned?

Tags: multiple-regression

Can someone describe to me in laymen terms what Q2 values mean with regards to PLSR

I understand that it is a cross validation number, but i have no idea what it is saying.  only that the model is better the closer to 1 it is.  is it the correlation coefficient?

Comment: Please explain what "Q2" and "PLSR" refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks anyway, but i have found the answer!

thought I would leave it here in case someone else has the same question.

In summary... the Q2 is a statistical measure of the "goodness of prediction" (0-1)
0= no prediction ability in the model
1= perfect prediction of the model.

here is a link to the paper I found useful, but the best explanation I have found is in Multi and megavariate data analysis Part 1. Basic pinciples and applications by Eriksson *et al*

http://www.libpls.net/publication/PLS_basic_2001.pdf